# "Youtube Data API" quota extension application form does not work

Tags: youtube-api, youtube-data-api

I entered the required fields in the form below, but I get the error message "There was a problem submitting the form. Please try again."
https://support.google.com/youtube/contact/yt_api_form?hl=en

User agents (browser, PC, network) have changed. The problem was not solved.

I tried it every few days and the problem continues.

Hopefully the form will be sent successfully and the entered content and application will reach Youtube management.

Whether the application is approved is another story.

Answer (score 0):

I encountered this same issue and it turned out there was a hidden error saying my the files I attached are more than 20mb, even though each video itself was under 20mb. I removed the attachments so the total of all files was under and it worked.

Comment: It doesn't answer the question

Comment: Thank you!
The problem has been solved!
As you say, the attached file was actually over 20MB on disk.
By successfully compressing some files so that it does not exceed 20MB, the form has been successfully submitted.

Comment: A hidden error? This sounds like a way for people to finally know why the form isn't being sent. Is this something you found in the console? By inspecting the http response? Where did you find this hidden error?